# issues with .off("DOMSubtreeModified")

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have logic like this

```
$('.myElement').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {

   if(something == true) {
      $('.myElement').off('DOMSubtreeModified');

      //Execute some code
   }

});
```

Will the `//Execute some code` be executed after I remove `'DOMSubtreeModified'` listener? I do this to ensure that same code is not executed if certain condition is met, hence need to stop listening to dom changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.myElement').off('DOMSubtreeModified', arguments.callee);
```

Comment: could you please explain the  arguments.callee bit?

Comment: While binding you are providing an anonymous function, so to refer the function being called I'm using `arguments.callee`. Means remove the currently executing function from binding for 'DOMSubtreeModified'.

Comment: I need to finish the //Execute some code bit after doing .off() doesn't  arguments.callee mean that it will not be executed?

Comment: No rest of the code will execute as usual. It just mean any further 'DOMSubtreeModified' event will not trigger this function's execution.

Comment: @Vivek, how to activate DOMSubtreeModified within this very function again?

Comment: @Nolesh To bind the event again under some condition you could again use the bind (.on) `arguments.callee` as 2ns argument.
Also could you tell what exactly is not working? Can you create a JSFiddle with the problem?

Comment: @Vivek, please take a look at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbv08pdf/). It's quite silly example, but reflects an issue. As you can see, this code works in FF, and doesn't work in Chrome

Comment: @Nolesh I am currently using chrome Version 70.0.3538.102.
And this is working with me.

Although I just made a slight change in the function for key press event:
Replaced `$('#result').html($(this).val())` with `$('#result').text($(this).val())` (Just because the results were little messy)

What worked for me:
 - Key press (enter) takes the value and update the #result
 - Which triggered the `DOMSubtreeModified` callback
 - Update worked
 - Rebinding worked

Could you explain,what exactly didn't work

Comment: @Vivek, When I tried to run this code using Chrome at work, it didn't unbind the callback. Although both examples work well even in Edge at home. It seems to me I was using a very old version of Chrome.

Comment: Cool. Also maybe you could prevent all the complexity with `arguments.callee` by using a named function.